# button started shifting on clicking of pagination button -angular bootstrap ui pagination

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using angular bootstrap `UI` pagination for showing the results on next and previous button. The result sets is been shown correctly. But I'm getting the following issue while clicking on the pagination button. The button started to shift towards right when I click button  item no 6, 7 and so on.
How can I achieve it without moving the buttons position.
Please find the plunker sample for reference.

link here : https://plnkr.co/edit/wpy2WaCxzcc6YbmnaREl?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Pagination to solve problem:

```
<div class="row">
                        <pagination ng-model="page"
                                    page="pagingInfo.page"
                                    total-items="pagingInfo.totalItems"
                                    items-per-page="pagingInfo.itemsPerPage"
                                    ng-change="selectPage(page)"
                                    max-size="5"
                                    rotate="false"
                                    boundary-links="true"></pagination>
                    </div>
```

Comment: can u please provide me a working view of it in jsfiddle or plunker

Comment: Yes One minute Pleas.

Comment: this link containt on multi example of Pagination http://jsfiddle.net/consultwithmike/619ryubL/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But this issue does not resolve my problem. The button is been shifting towards right position, when I'm clicking next button. Here is the jsfiddle which does the same--> http://jsfiddle.net/pogf1cf9/ . I have update your jsfiddle, but still I'm facing the same problem. Can you provide me a solution for not shifting the next button when I'm clicking button 6,7,8 and so on.

Comment: I am Updating the Jsfiddle and the problem is solve http://jsfiddle.net/pogf1cf9/2/

Comment: This sample(http://jsfiddle.net/pogf1cf9/2/ ) provided by you shows that on clicking next button after 9, the complete pagination element started shifting towards right. Is there any way to not shift the pagination element. I need to stick the pagination element on the given width. I noticed that when the button element changes from one digits to two digits the button width gets increased. So the complete button size is shifting towards right. Is there any way to prevent it for not shifting towards right.